# What's a RESTful url for a linked item?

Tags: c#, rest

This is going to be a web service that returns a JSON object. Currently, I'm using C# technology and simply using ASP.Net MVC to create the calls. This is not a web page, so SEO is not a concern.

I've come across a number of instances where I want to get the "next" or "previous" item in a list. 
For example, I've got a service that returns a featured photo.
http://myservice.com/photos/123
which returns a JSON

```
{"name": "At_The_Concert", "id": "123", "src": "http://myservice.com/photostore/123.jpg"}
```

The client (Ajax, Mobile device, etc.) of this service wants to know what the “next” item is going to be. I’m struggling about what the url should be.

- http://myservice.com/photos/123/next
- http://myservice.com/photos/next/123
- http://myservice.com/nextphotos/123

or maybe the id property should just be a parameter

http://myservice.com/photos/next?photoId=123

Or maybe this is entirely wrong and it should be like

http://myservice.com/photos/?method=getNextPhoto&photoId=123

though with .Net's routing, it might be easier to write it as
http://myservice.com/photos/method/getNextPhoto?photoId=123

I’m relatively new to web services and REST. I get the basic CRUD for REST, but I don’t know what is the best practice for creating more custom urls, in this case the “next” photo.
Is there an accepted RESTful practice?

Comment: the last three **are not RESTful** they are RPC over HTTP

Comment: That's interesting, because the 2nd to last (?method=) I based off Flickr's REST API.

Comment: just because they call it REST doesn't mean they got it right

Comment: That is very true.

Answer (score 14):

Do it this way:

```
{"name": "At_The_Concert", "id": "123", "src": "http://myservice.com/photostore/123.jpg",
"next": "http://myservice.com/photos/345/",
"prev": "http://myservice.com/photos/901/"}
```

Comment: +1 for the sane way to do it. Keeps the Prev/Next links 'clean' too.

Comment: A cool URL never changes.  "http://myservice.com/photos/123/next" might point to different pictures depending on filter settings or user authorizations or day of week or phase of moon.

Comment: But it does change. If I remove photos or add new photos, there will be a different "next" photo.

Comment: There will be a different value associated with "next" in the JSON reply.  The URL for a given photo never changes.  You don't want to have "myservice.com/photos/123/next" and ""myservice.com/photos/345" BOTH point to the same photo.  You want "myservice.com/photos/345" to be the one, only and unchanging for photo 345.  Since "myservice.com/photos/123/next" is always changing, you simply do not want to ever use it.

Comment: I'm thinking that you're right. This was the original path that I went down. I was using a LinkedListNode<T> in the middle tier to generate the data. Everything was nice until I tried to serialize my LinkedListNode and . . . recursion blowup. /next seems like such a nice solution from the middle tier point of view, but alas, it does violate the Thou Shalt Have One Url And Only One Url Commandment.

Comment: "... recursion blowup..."?  You might want to ask that question separately.

Comment: Recursion blowup means that the LinkedListNode generic type doesn't serialize. I already have the answer -- create something custom. I was hoping to avoid that extra work.

Comment: @John: Why serialize the entire list?  You only want two modes.

Comment: Without going into much detail -- the a LinkedListNode<T> Prev and Next and just id pointers, as above, but entire objects. So when .Net tries to serialize the property "Next", it gets another full node . . . which has another "Next" node, which gets serialized . . .

Answer (score 0):

Having the next function be an operation server-side requires state information, particularly if you are involving filtering.  This violates REST.

It seems more appropriate to provide a directory list at http://myservice.com/photos, and let the app call the appropriate http://myserivce.com/photos/id link when hitting next/previous.  With this method, the filtering logic would be on the client, and it could be modified/reset without having to call the service again.

Alternatively, you could have request parameters into the http://myservice.com/photos that returns a filtered list.  Naturally, this would require additional service calls if the filter changed, so you may wish to stick with the former suggestion.

The end result would be the same, however.  Your state would reside where it should - in the client app as opposed to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to look at [OData and Service Operations](https://web.archive.org/web/20160227165101/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/writingdata_services/archive/2011/03/28/calling-service-operations-from-the-client.aspx) it will guarantee RESTful style of your calls.